# Error: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, error-handling, compiler-errors, jupyter-notebook, syntax-error

I'm trying to run this code, however I got TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'. What can I do to remove this error? I'm still a beginner at using python. Hope anyone can help me.

```
author = 'Rocco'

    import math
    
    import numpy as np 
    import cv2 from skimage 
    import feature from scipy 
    import ndimage 

class PHogFeatures(): 
def init(self): 
pass
    
    def get_features(self, image_path, bins=8, angle=360., pyramid_levels=3):

        feature_vec = self.phog(image_path, bins, angle, pyramid_levels)
        feature_vec = feature_vec.T[0]  # Transpose vector, take the first array
        return feature_vec

    def phog(self, image_path, bin, angle, pyramid_levels): 
         grayscale_img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\user\Documents\FYP\Dataset\Train', 0) # 0 converts it to grayscale 
         bh = np.array([]) 
         bv = np.array([])
    
    if np.sum(np.sum(grayscale_img)) > 100.:
         edges_canny = feature.canny(grayscale_img, sigma=math.sqrt(2)) 
         [GradientY, GradientX] = np.gradient(np.double(grayscale_img)) 
         GradientYY = np.gradient(GradientY)[1] # Take only the first matrix 
         Gr = np.sqrt((GradientX * GradientX + GradientY * GradientY))
    
         index = GradientX == 0.
         index = index.astype(int)  # Convert boolean array to an int array
         GradientX[np.where(index > 0)] = np.power(10, -5)
         YX = GradientY / GradientX
```

[image: Here is the screenshot of error that I got]

Comment: Shouldn't argument of `cv2.imread` point to a file? Currently it looks like a directory path.

Comment: Could you type in the traceback instead of linking an image?  Also, could you fix your indentation so that it matches your core?  What you have now is not valid syntax.

Comment: See https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/26/opencv-resolving-nonetype-errors/